# correct setting of eval_set in multiclass classification xgboost python , error is " Check failed: preds.size() == info.labels_.size()"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, xgboost

i have a multiclass classification problem with 3 classes [-1,0,1] .
i'd like to use eval_set in xgboost. but it fails with error:

```
rank_metric.cc:88: Check failed: preds.size() == info.labels_.size() (270 
vs. 90) label size predict size not match'
```

when i run

```
  modelfit=model.fit(Xtrain,ytrain)
```

it runs fine

```
modelfit=model.fit(Xtrain,ytrain,eval_set = [(Xtest, ytest)])
```

generates above error

i tried all eval_metric  available for multiclass and they all generate same error.

model is following:

```
xgb.XGBClassifier(n_jobs = -1,objective = 'multi:softmax',
                num_class=3, eval_metric = 'mlogloss',           
tree_method='approx', scale_pos_weight=1,
            **{'subsample':0.5,'colsample_bylevel':1, 'colsample_bytree': 
1, 'gamma':0, 'learning_rate':0.3,'max_delta_step': 0, 'max_depth': 10, 
'min_child_weight': 1, 'n_estimators': 10, 'reg_alpha': 0, 'reg_lambda': 
0})

ipdb> modelfit.predict(Xtest)
array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,
    1., -1.,  1.,  0., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
   -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
   -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
   -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])
ipdb> len(modelfit.predict(Xtest))
90
ipdb> len(ytest)
90
ipdb> ytest
array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  0., -1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
    1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
    1.,  1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
    1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -1.,
   -1., -1., -1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
    0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

as can be seen from debugger output , len of predict(Xtest) and ytest are both 90.
why xgboost generates the error?

Answer (score 0):

looks like a bug in 0.80 version
does work when upgraded to xgboost 0.82